# Can't validate form in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, forms, validation

I tried to validate a custom form but without success.

My form:

```
<div class ="shop-container">
    <h3>CLUBLOGIN</h3>
        <div class="shop-container">
        <form data-mage-init='{"validation": {}}' action="<?php echo $this->getUrl("clubshop/index/index")?>" method="post" id="clubshop-form-custom">
            <div class="club-img">
            </div>
            <div class="club-inputs">
                <div class="club-name">
                <label class="" for="email"><span>Naam</span></label><br>
                    <input name="club-name" value="" autocomplete="off" id="club-name" type="input" class="input-text" title="Naam" >
                </div>
                <div class="club-email">
                    <label class="" for="email"><span>Emailadres</span></label><br>
                    <input name="club-mail" value="" id="club-email" type="input" class="input-text" title="email" ><br>
                </div>
                <div class="club-button">
                    <br>
                    <div class="primary"><button type="submit" class="action login primary" name="send" id="send2"><span>Inloggen</span></button></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

What I tried so far in my **phtml**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

   var dataForm = $('#clubshop-form-custom');
   dataForm.mage('validation', {});

});
</script>
```

and 
for this method i changed my button into input but still no scuccess.

```
<script>
require([
  'jquery',
  'mage/mage',
], function($){
   $( "#send2" ).click(function() {        
       $('input[name="club-email"]').validation();
       if(!$('input[name="club-email"]').validation('isValid')){
           return false;
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your requirement no need to add more js.

Just Add below code in input box

```
data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"
```

Check below code

```
<input name="club-name"  class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}" >
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank for your answer but still not working

Comment: I have checked its working fine :- https://prnt.sc/gnfuea, Do you working on any popup design

Comment: magneto 1 or 2?

Comment: after i deploy my form was working. thank you very much shyam

Comment: but this works only if a refresh the page. do you know why?